# Pass values into AuthorizeCore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing my own AuthorizeCore attribute for handling access rights within my MVC application. Is there any way I can pass more than just the HTTPContext into the method? I would like to refrain from putting information into the users session just to get stuff in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats the interface definition that requires the method signature to be in the format it is which limits to httpContext

AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore Method

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(
    HttpContextBase httpContext
)
```

You could try to see if storing in HttpContext.Items works instead of the session.

Comment: Yea I figured as much. I know I could store in the user session, but I wanted to try and avoid that... Thanks